# How can I print "print me 1" and "print me 2" from html code?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I have this HTML code,

```
<div class="_1GGPkHIiaumnRMT-S1cU29"><span>print me 1</span><span><div class="_2ZBv5UiBzOiApuonYSpb92"><div>patates</div></div></span><span>print me 2</span></div>
```

how can I get "print me 1" and "print me 2"?

I am learning web scraping in Python using BeautifulSoup.

```
for subcat in category.find_all("div"):
        print(subcat)
```

Comment: that's not html code, that's only a string. if you have actual html please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53892885/edit) the question and include it please. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Logic**

```
1) Encapsulate HTML in a single quoted string.
2) Initialize BeautifulSoup
3) Locate all Span tags where presumably only text will occur in between tags
4) Iterate across all returned values (strings) that have span in them
5) If div or any other tag occurs (other tag case not covered in answer) then ignore record
6) Otherwise print value, after removing span tags
```

**Code**

```
#import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data returned from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


category = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_1GGPkHIiaumnRMT-S1cU29"><span>print me 1</span><span><div class="_2ZBv5UiBzOiApuonYSpb92"><div>patates</div></div></span><span>print me 2</span></div>')

def printSpan(s):
  s = s.find_all("span")
  for string in s:
    if len(string.find_all("div")) != 0:
      continue
    else:
      print (str(string).replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>", ""))

printSpan(category)
```

Comment: good answer. Only thing I'd add/change is you don't need to do `.replace` or convert to `str` if you use BeautifulSoup `.text` function: change: `print (str(string).replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>", ""))` to simply `print (string.text)`